# Does Form Builder handle relationships?

Tags: formbuilder

Using Form Builder I want to add an individual and an organisation and so the individual would have the relationship 'contact for' the organisation. I can't see a way of doing that - is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Create a form and add an Individual, an Organization and a Relationship.

On the Relationship tab, use the Values section:

- click 'Add value' and select 'Contact A'
- click in the search box and choose 'Individual1' in the pop-up
- click 'Add value' and select 'Contact B'
- click in the search box and choose 'Organization1' in the pop-up
- click 'Add value' and select 'Relationship Type'
- in the pop-up, select 'Key contact of'

[image]

This works on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org (5.56.alpha1) but may not on older versions.

== Edit ==

If your version supports relationships they should show on the pop-up when you hit '+' as here:

[image]

Comment: I'm using 5.49 & so maybe that's the problem as I don't see any relationship tabs in Form Builder.  Thanks for the fast reply - I'll try with a later release

Comment: OK, added a screenshot to show where relationships will show up if they are supported.

Comment: This isn't in 5.49 but is in 5.53 - hard to keep up!